# Debian: Remove redundant package terminology

Tags: command-line, apt, regular-expression

When I install a LAMP server environment on Debians I use this code:

```
apt-get upgrade lamp-server^ php-cli php-curl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-gd python-certbot-apache -y
```

If I add more `php-X` packages it becomes uglylically long.

Is there a way to shorten it a bit like as follows?

```
apt-get upgrade lamp-server^ php-cli|curl|mbstring|mcrypt|gd python-certbot-apache -y
```

Comment: I may sound like a broken record, but `apt-get upgrade` upgrades all installed packages (in addition to doing what you’re asking it to do here). `apt-get install` is the usual command to install packages. (Of course, if you do want to upgrade at the same time, why not, I suppose.)

Comment: @StephenKitt as the actual sequence is longer and contains other utilities likely to already come with my distro, indeed, I desire to upgrade all utilities in the sequence. Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use bash [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) to generate the arguments with the same prefix.

The correct syntax would be:

```
apt-get upgrade lamp-server^ php-{cli,curl,mbstring,mcrypt,gd} python-certbot-apache -y
```